# black screen when connecting to xrdp server

Tags: networking, arch-linux, raspberry-pi, xrdp

I have installed archLinux on rapberry-pi, and everything is just working fine, till i have came across setting up remote dektop. am trying to access xrdp server using remmina
client from another linux distro, but all i can get is black screen with mouse pointer, I have tried almost all solutions that i can find over Internet forums but none of them has resolved my issue I have also gone through [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=192410) issue  but that also doesn't work for me. I have installed xrdp, tigerVNC, vino using (AUR)yaourt , also am using XFCE desktop , as it lightwieght and runs smooth on rapberry.

> status of vncserver.service by running .
>
> vncserver.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)    Loaded: loaded
>   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vncserver.service; disabled; vendor p
>   Active: inactive (dead)

**also output of /var/log/xrdp.log**

> [20161126-14:37:07] [INFO ] An established connection closed to
>   endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 11 [20161126-14:37:08] [INFO ] An
>   established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 11
>   [20161126-14:37:09] [INFO ] An established connection closed to
>   endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 11 [20161126-14:37:10] [ERROR] Failure
>   to connect to sesman: 127.0.0.1 port: 3350 [20161126-14:37:10] [INFO ]
>   An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 11
>   [20161126-14:37:10] [DEBUG] returnvalue from xrdp_mm_connect 1

am not sure if the above mentioned info is enough but that's all  I had at the moment, so let me know guys if anyone have solution to this issue!